# GATLING TESTS -Storing different env variable and run the same gatling tests in different test/dev enviroment

Tags: environment-variables, gatling

would like to run the same gatling test in different environment (test and dev enviornment etc), how to fetch urls from different env and use that to run the same gatling test

```
    like env.qa - store all qa urls
         env.dev - store all dev urls
         env.prod  - store all prod urls
    
    
    Pass env as a run time variable that should go and run the gatling in test in that particular environment
    and ./gradlew clean gatlingRun -DGATLING_ENV="dev"
    ./gradlew clean gatlingRun -DGATLING_ENV="qa"
    ./gradlew clean gatlingRun -DGATLING_ENV="prod"

something like this.
```